# how to ng-repeat a scope function in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a scope function below that returns **uniqueUsers**. If I want to output the text in HTML using ng-repeat, how do I go about doing this?

```
// update filter functions
$scope.updateFilter = function (start, end) {
  // console.log(start.unix());
  thisMonthUsers = [];
  records.forEach(function (entry) {
    var entryStart = entry.f[3].__text / 1000;
    var entryEnd = entry.f[4].__text / 1000;
    if (!(entryEnd < start.unix() || entryStart > end.unix())) {
      thisMonthUsers.push(entry.f[1].__text);
    }
  });
  var uniqueUsers = thisMonthUsers.filter(Unique); // unique
    return uniqueUsers;
}
```

So far I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="uniqueUsers in updateFilter">{{ uniqueUsers() }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code could do the trick:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="user in users = uniqueUsers() | filter">...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Gotcha. I just didn't put the right function in. Thanks!